# Deploying Django app with GoDaddy domains and cPanel

Tags: django, deployment, cpanel, godaddy-api

I am trying to deploy my first Django app. I already own the domain using goDaddy domains and I am trying to set up the Django application. I am trying to find the terminal in the Advanced section in cPanel but it is not there. how can I use the terminal?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have the "Setup Python App" option in your Cpanel? because I can't see it in the picture you shared.

Comment: I do have "setup Python App" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Create python app from `setup python app` given in cpanel. No need to put anything in any other field, that will be self-filled once you click on create button. Copy the path of virtual env that you got after clicking create button.

**Step 2:**
Upload your django project files inside your python app with all the updated config settings like database, allowed urls, static url, and all other.

**Step 3:**

> if you have terminal:
> Open the terminal from your cpanel and paste the path of virtual env in the terminal in press enter. Install all your pip dependencies. Run collectstatic, migration and etc.

> if you don't have terminal:
> place all the project-related dependencies in the requirements.txt file and upload that to your python app folder in the file manager. Then go to setup python app option, there you will find `configuration file` option select requirements.txt  by clicking `Run pip install` button then next to it you will find `Execute Python Script`, You can use that to execute all your collectstatic, migrate, etc commands.

**Step 4:**
Go back to file manager inside your python app folder and Paste the following line in your `passenger_wsgi.py` after removing all of its contents.

```
from <Your django project name>.wsgi import application
```

**Step 5**
Get back to setup python app option and click on restart button, and boom. You are done.

Comment: I did the first two steps but for some reason I cant find the terminal in cpanel